# Masking Textbox without affecting Model value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, types, credit-card, mask

I need to mask the input box/text box in ASP.NET MVC 2 for Credit Card. But the masking shouldn't affect its binding to its model.

I am trying to do something like this:
[DataType(DataType.MaskedCreditCard)]
similar to:
[DataType(DataType.Password)]

Comment: Does DataType.Password not work? It would be helpful if you could describe in more detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to create something similar to DataType.Password for credit card masking. DataType.Password doesn't show the text as we type it. But instead it will mask the characters. So I want the similar functionality for credit card where all the numbers except last four will be masked. 

If possible I want to mask it when the textbox loose focus.

Comment: and then what? un-mask it when it gains focus? I'd give that a big WTF if I had to enter my CC into such a control. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: What happens when you filled out your credit card information on the page forgot to close the form or submit the form? Others can easily steal your numbers.

Anyway, if you know then please tell me the answer. Leave the use of it to me.

Comment: This isn't answering your question but I would either mask it completely or leave it unmasked. I agree with dotjoe with the strange behaviour.

If you are concerned enough about the "What happens..." then treat is as you would senstiive password information and mask it.

At least if someone is typing and it is masked they will be familiar with this pattern for other sensitive information such as passwords.

P.S I don't know too many people that would walk off half way through a sensitive form submission :p

Comment: I agree with both of you, dotjoe and Joshua. But its funny that no body understood the real problem. Its not the matter of choice that I have but the requirement. It seems that you haven't worked with the client who has the weird requirements and they don' want to change the requirement no matter what. :(

Anyway, I have solved the problem. Now I have Credit card masking textbox.

:) :)

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery mask and unmask? Not sure if it might solve your problem. http://www.miuaiga.com/index.cfm/2010/11/12/jQuery-Masked-Input-change-masking-based-on-a-selected-value-with-unmask

Comment: @anit.lacoul I am stuck up with the same situation, can you please tell  how you have solved this problem

Comment: @AnitLacoul please, if you found an answer please share, because others could find it useful.